# Testing for enum value fails if one has associated value?

Tags: enums, swift

I'm testing this in the Playground and I'm not sure how to do this. With a normal enum that doesn't have associated values, everything is fine.

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case North
    case South
    case East
    case West
}

var direction = CompassPoint.East

if direction != .West {
    println("Go West!")
}
```

However, if one of my enums has an associated value, the direction test fails with this error: could not find member 'West'

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case North(Int)
    case South
    case East
    case West
}

var direction = CompassPoint.East

if direction != .West {
    println("Go West!")
}
```

What can I do to allow for this test?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Enumerations are automatically `Equatable` when they have a raw value that's `Equatable`. In your first case, the raw value is assumed to be `Int`, but it would work if you'd given it another specific type like `UInt32` or even `String`.

Once you add an associated value, however, this automatic conformance with `Equatable` doesn't happen any more, since you can declare this:

```
let littleNorth = CompassPoint.North(2)
let bigNorth = CompassPoint.North(99999)
```

Are those equal? How should Swift know? You have to tell it, by declaring the `enum` as `Equatable` and then implementing the `==` operator:

```
enum CompassPoint : Equatable {
    case North(Int)
    case South
    case East
    case West
}

public func ==(lhs:CompassPoint, rhs:CompassPoint) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.North(let lhsNum), .North(let rhsNum)):
        return lhsNum == rhsNum
    case (.South, .South): return true
    case (.East, .East): return true
    case (.West, .West): return true
    default: return false
    }
}
```

Now you can test for equality or inequality, like this:

```
let otherNorth = CompassPoint.North(2)
println(littleNorth == bigNorth)            // false
println(littleNorth == otherNorth)          // true
```

Comment: The cases returning *true* can be combined to a single case:
`case (.South, .South), (.East, .East), (.West, .West): return true`

Comment: From Swift 4.1 due to [SE-0185](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md), Swift also supports synthesizing `Equatable` and `Hashable` for enums with associated values.