# Compiler error when comparing values of enum type with associated values?

Tags: swift, if-statement, enums, binary-operators

```
class MyClass 
{
    enum MyEnum {
        case FirstCase
        case SecondCase(Int)
        case ThirdCase
    }

    var state:MyEnum!

    func myMethod ()
    {
        if state! == MyEnum.FirstCase {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I get the compiler error pointing at the `if` statement::

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'MyClass.MyEnum'
>   operands

If instead, I use a `switch` statement, there is no problem:

```
switch state! {
    // Also, why do I need `!` if state is already an 
    // implicitly unwrapped optional? Is it because optionals also 
    // are internally enums, and the compiler gets confused?

case .FirstCase:
    // do something...

default:
    // (do nothing)
    break
}
```

However, the `switch` statement feels too verbose: I just want to `do something` for `.FirstCase`, and nothing otherwise. An `if` statement makes more sense.

What's going on with enums and `==` ?

**EDIT:** This is ultra-weird. After settling for the `switch` version and moving on to other (totally unrelated) parts of my code, and coming back, the `if`-statement version (comnparing force-unwrapped property against fixed enum case) is compiling with no errors. 
I can only conclude that it has something to do with some corrupted cache in the parser that got cleared along the way.

**EDIT 2** (Thanks @LeoDabus and @MartinR): It seems that the error appears when I set an associated value to the *other* enum case (not the one I am comparing against - in this case, .SecondCase). I still don't understand why that triggers this compiler error in particular ("Can't use binary operator '=='..."), or what that means.

Comment: you forgot to initialise state and you are forcing unwrapping it. add guard let state = state else { return } instead

Comment: This is dummy code with type and variable names changed, and most methods omitted. In my real code, the var **is** initialized. Either case, that should be a runtime issue at most. In reality, I am testing the value in `viewDidLoad()`, and the compiler can't know if it is initialized or not.

Comment: What Xcode version are you using? I don't get this error here

Comment: same as mine thats weird. Do you get the same error with my code? Your code compiles fine here

Comment: Is that your real code? As Leo said, it compiles without problem in Xcode 7 and 7.1. – Perhaps you have an enum with *associated values*?

Comment: No, it's not my real code (like I said above). Now that you mentioned it, there _was_ an associated value to the _other_ case of the enum (I have since removed it); but I still fail to see how that could cause the compiler error.

Comment: @NicolasMiari: Is *is* relevant, because enums with associated types do not have a default `==` operator.

Comment: Oh, I see; missed that one. Thanks a million.  The error message could have been a bit more explicit in that respect, though...

Comment: @NicolasMiari: Another option is to make your enum conform to `Equatable`, as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25726677/59541

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you said in a comment, your enumeration type actually has associated
values. In that case there is no default `==` operator for the enum type.

But you can use pattern matching even in an `if` statement (since Swift 2):

```
class MyClass {
    enum MyEnum {
        case FirstCase
        case SecondCase
        case ThirdCase(Int)
    }

    var state:MyEnum!

    func myMethod () {
        if case .FirstCase? = state {

        }
    }
}
```

Here `.FirstCase?` is a shortcut for `.Some(MyEnum.FirstCase)`.

In your switch-statement, `state` is not automatically unwrapped,
even if it is an implicitly unwrapped optional (otherwise you could
not match against `nil`). But the same pattern can be used here:

```
switch state {
case .FirstCase?:
    // do something...
default:
    break
}
```

---

**Update:** As of **Swift 4.1** (Xcode 9.3) the compiler can synthesize conformance to Equatable/Hashable for enums with associated values (if all their types are Equatable/Hashable). It suffices to declare the conformance:

```
class MyClass {
    enum MyEnum: Equatable {
        case firstCase
        case secondCase
        case thirdCase(Int)
    }

    var state:MyEnum!

    func myMethod () {
        if state  == .firstCase {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up not needing the associated value in my current code, so the `if` statement works as initially planned, but will remember this pattern for future reference.

Comment: @Martin R: Optional(E.A) == E.A // gives me true in Swift 2

Comment: @user3441734: Sorry, I don't get what you are asking.

Comment: Any way to do this in one line? E.g. `let isEqual: Bool = .FirstCase == state`

Comment: @BallpointBen: Sure: `let isEqual = { _ -> Bool in if case .FirstCase? = state { return true } else { return false } }()` is a single line :)

Comment: From Swift 4.1 due to [SE-0185](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md), Swift also supports synthesizing `Equatable` and `Hashable` for enums with associated values.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyClass {
    enum MyEnum {
        case FirstCase
        case SecondCase
        case ThirdCase
    }

    var state: MyEnum!

    func myMethod()  {
        guard let state = state else { return }
        if state == MyEnum.FirstCase {
            // Do something
            print(true)
        } else {
             print(false)
        }
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.state = .FirstCase
myClass.myMethod()
myClass.state = .SecondCase
myClass.myMethod()
```

Comment: What happens if instead of first unwrapping with `guard`, you skip it and just try to compare `state! == MyEnum.FirstCase`?

Comment: @NicolasMiari your code runs fine here as long as you initialise state property

Comment: I repeat: the compiler (static analyzer?) has **no way to know** if the property is initialized or not at the location where it is used (`viewDidLoad`), and I am force-unwrapping it (which I souldn't need to, since it is an implicitly unwrapped optional to begin with). And the compiler error I was getting had nothing to do with initialization, but with comparing two enums **of the same type** (?????)