# How to compare Swift enumerations which include additional constructor values

Tags: swift, enums

I have a problem on how to compare some enumerations. Let me show you the most simple example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    enum MyEnum {
        case FirstCase
        case SecondCase(subvalue: Int) // coment out to be able to compile
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let value: MyEnum = .FirstCase

        if value == .FirstCase { // will not compile if "case SecondCase(subvalue: Int)" is included into the enum
            print("They are the same")
        }
    }
}
```

So the `case SecondCase(subvalue: Int)` makes the `if` statement impossible for some reason. By removing it the code compiles.

So is there a way to create a normal comparison for such enumerations? Is this a Swift bug?

**Just to clear up how this kind of enums are used:**

```
    enum MyEnum {
        case FirstCase
        case SecondCase(subvalue: Int) // coment out to be able to compile

        func printValue() {
            switch self {
            case .FirstCase:
                print("First case")
            case .SecondCase(let subvalue):
                print("Second case \(subvalue)")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is very handy for cases such as defining the endpoints which require additional parameters which is exactly my case.

**And there is a very silly trick to actually do the check but you must use a `switch` statement:**

```
        switch value {
        case .FirstCase:
            print("They are the same")
        default:
            break
        }
```

This compiles while a normal `if` does not!

Comment: In your case it would be `if case .FirstCase = value { .. }`

Comment: I think proposed duplicate does not say much about enum with associated value, so should not be considered as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The only thing that is missing is the "case". Unbelievable!

Comment: @OOPer: Actually it does, but it was clarified only in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559936/compiler-error-when-comparing-values-of-enum-type#comment54900150_33559936. Unfortunately, OP did not update the question itself.

Comment: @MartinR, seems you are right, and seems it's taken correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to combine this with a "where"? "if let customUrlPath = customUrlPath where case .Custom = endpoint"

Comment: @MaticOblak: `if let customUrlPath = customUrlPath, case .Custom = endpoint { ... }` should work (but that might be worth a separate question and answer :)

Comment: Thank you. How about you just create an answer here with all of these cases? A big bonus would be if you could elaborate this code as this makes no sense to me at all. Why the "case", why a single "=", why is the "where" invalid... This case is as if was a different language.

Comment: It's because the `if case` statement is an [Enumeration Case Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID424). I'm not exactly sure why they went with `=` over `==` but I'm guessing it mirrors the [Optional Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID520) `if let x = x`.

Comment: This is exactly why it is so weird. The optional pattern creates a redeclared variable which is used in pretty much any language. But the scope of the new variable is limited to the closures (a guard is an exception as it is inverted though). But more importantly we gain another variable which does not seem to be the case in the  Enumeration Case Pattern. This pattern actually looks as if it was "if a left value can be assigned by another value" like the ObjectiveC if((self = [super init])) just very unnatural.